# Unsubscribing Facebook admins and regular users from notifications

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

What is the best way to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) this code up?

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_user

  def unsubscribe
    if @facebook_admin && @facebook_admin.auth_key == params[:auth_key]
      @facebook_admin.update_notification_settings(params[:type] => false)
    elsif @user && @user.auth_key == params[:auth_key]
      @user.update_notification_settings(params[:type] => false)
    end
  end

  private

  def load_user
    if params[:type].present?
      if params[:facebook_admin_id].present?
        @facebook_admin = FacebookAdmin.find_by_id(params[:facebook_admin_id])
      elsif params[:user_id].present?
        @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Verbosity of a controller is typically a signal of dubious design. As I see it, you have two sensible options:

1. If `User` and `FacebookAdmin` are two very different user entities: they should be treated in two separate controllers.
2. If `User` and `FacebookAdmin` are very similar (i.e. `FacebookAdmin` inherits from `User`): they can share the same controller but use always `@user` as variable. This way the code will be simplified dramatically.

What you should not have is a controller full of conditional branches, that will be an unmaintainable mess (and awful to test).